# how to set header font color in iText

Tags: itext

```
HeaderFooter header = 
      new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("test", new Font(bf_times)), false);
header.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
header.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0xB5091E));

document.setHeader(header);
```

I want to set the Font color for `test` to white (`FFFFFF`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Font is the class holding the color.

```
Font font = new Font(bf_times)
font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

This should do it.