# how can i change color of text in a cell in itext pdf?

Tags: itext

I just want to change color of "PAN DETAILS"(cell text) in my code please tell with a good example.

```
 PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
         table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
         PdfPCell cellsss;
         cellsss = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PAN DETAILS"));
         cellsss.setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.BLACK);
         cellsss.setColspan(0);
         cellsss.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
         BaseColor myColorpan = WebColors.getRGBColor("#b60548");
         cellsss.setBackgroundColor(myColorpan);
         cellsss.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
         table2.addCell(cellsss);
         cellsss = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PAN DETAILS"));
         cellsss.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
         document.add(table2);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe a duplicate. But anyway: The Font class holds the color so you have to set the color in the Font-class.

```
Font font = new Font(bf_times)
font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

This must be set in the `Phrase`:

```
new Phrase("PAN DETAILS", font)
```

From the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460955/how-to-set-header-font-color-in-itext).